# How to use NLTK in Jython, or PY4J cross platforn?

Tags: java, python, android, jython, py4j

I have two questions, this could go into different directions based on opinion, but as of right now I am writing a Java/Kotlin API. So far it is compatible across all platforms, excluding IOS(have not tested).

A few of the tasks it runs is python using PY4J but the way the API calls the python script to start the PY4J connection is

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python script.py") # Is there a better way to do this?
```

Which is fine until it comes to Android. Will Android be able to use this method? If so, the question is answered and finished there.

If not, is there a way to embed a python interpreter into a JAR file? Java project?
I like Jython, but I could not get NLTK to work with it.

1) Is there a way to make Jython work with NLTK : If not,

2) Is there a way to use PY4J in Python?

3) Is there a way to embed a custom Python interpreter in Java/JAR?

Feel free to edit my question, code and title. I don't do this much, so it is probably sloppy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was silly, but I will keep it up since this was a real question. You can install python3 directly into the JAR. When the python installation screen shows up you can just install it into a folder inside your Java project.

For the Android part, there is a python package called p4a, python-for-android. You can create a python interpreter with dependencies. This should work.